# query dealing with average grade point averages

Tags: sql

I am having problems trying to get this sql statement to work.the gap is supposed to be calculated like this. Major GPA is calculated in the same way as GPA except that only the courses from the student's major are included in the calculation. For example, suppose a CS student got an A in a CS class and a B in a Math class, the student's major GPA would be 4.0.

> List the students and their major GPA. The results do not need to include the students who have not taken any classes in their major.

So far I have the below query, which doesn't fully return what i want.

```
select sum(value*units)/sum(units) as GPA ,f.name from faculty f
inner join sections s on s.instructor_id = f.id
inner join courses c on c.id=s.id
inner join grades g on g.value =c.units
group by f.name
```

the table i get is

```
name    gpa
Art     4.00
Bob     4.00
Pat     3.30
Amy     3.30
Kim     3.30
Sue     3.30
Joe     2.70
Lee     2.70
Max    2.70
```

Which is almost what I want, but it shows gpas for students who didn't even take any classes.

Database looks like

```
   create table departments (
    id      integer primary key,
    name    varchar(255)
);

insert into departments (id, name) values (10, 'Computer Science');
insert into departments (id, name) values (20, 'Math');
insert into departments (id, name) values (30, 'Drama');

 create table students (
    id              integer primary key,
    name            varchar(255),
    graduation_date date,
    major_id        integer references departments(id)
);

insert into students (id, name, graduation_date, major_id) values
    (1, 'Joe', null, 10);
insert into students (id, name, graduation_date, major_id) values
    (2, 'Amy', '2009-04-22', 20);
insert into students (id, name, graduation_date, major_id) values
    (3, 'Max', null, 10);
insert into students (id, name, graduation_date, major_id) values
    (4, 'Sue', '2009-01-10', 20);
insert into students (id, name, graduation_date, major_id) values
    (5, 'Bob', '2009-03-05', 30);
insert into students (id, name, graduation_date, major_id) values
    (6, 'Kim', null, 20);
insert into students (id, name, graduation_date, major_id) values
    (7, 'Art', null, 30);
insert into students (id, name, graduation_date, major_id) values
    (8, 'Pat', '2005-07-11', 20);
insert into students (id, name, graduation_date, major_id) values
    (9, 'Lee', null, 10);

create table grades (
    id          integer primary key,
    letter      varchar(255) not null unique,
    value       real
);

insert into grades (id, letter, value) values (1, 'A', 4.0);
insert into grades (id, letter, value) values (2, 'A-', 3.7);
insert into grades (id, letter, value) values (3, 'B+', 3.3);
insert into grades (id, letter, value) values (4, 'B', 3.0);
insert into grades (id, letter, value) values (5, 'B-', 2.7);
insert into grades (id, letter, value) values (6, 'C+', 2.3);
insert into grades (id, letter, value) values (7, 'C', 2.0);
insert into grades (id, letter, value) values (8, 'C-', 1.7);
insert into grades (id, letter, value) values (9, 'D+', 1.3);
insert into grades (id, letter, value) values (10, 'D', 1.0);
insert into grades (id, letter, value) values (11, 'D-', 0.7);
insert into grades (id, letter, value) values (12, 'F', 0.0);
insert into grades (id, letter) values (13, 'CR');
insert into grades (id, letter) values (14, 'NC');

create table courses (
    id              integer primary key,
    title           varchar(255),
    units           integer,
    department_id   integer references departments(id)
);

insert into courses (id, title, units, department_id) values
    (12, 'Databases', 4, 10);
insert into courses (id, title, units, department_id) values
    (22, 'Compilers', 4, 10);
insert into courses (id, title, units, department_id) values
    (32, 'Calculus 1', 4, 20);
insert into courses (id, title, units, department_id) values
    (42, 'Algebra', 4, 20);
insert into courses (id, title, units, department_id) values
    (52, 'Acting', 4, 30);
insert into courses (id, title, units, department_id) values
    (62, 'Elocution', 2, 30);
insert into courses (id, title, units, department_id) values
    (72, 'Calculus 2', 4, 20);
insert into courses (id, title, units, department_id) values
    (82, 'Topology', 4, 20);

create table sections (
    id              integer primary key,
    course_id       integer not null references courses(id),
    instructor_id   integer references faculty(id),
    year            integer
);

insert into sections (id, course_id, instructor_id, year) values
    (12, 12, 6, 2007);
insert into sections (id, course_id, instructor_id, year) values
    (13, 12, 1, 2008);
insert into sections (id, course_id, instructor_id, year) values
    (14, 22, 1, 2008);
insert into sections (id, course_id, instructor_id, year) values
    (23, 12, 6, 2009);
insert into sections (id, course_id, instructor_id, year) values
    (24, 22, 1, 2009);
insert into sections (id, course_id, instructor_id, year) values
    (32, 32, 2, 2008);
insert into sections (id, course_id, instructor_id, year) values
    (33, 32, 2, 2009);
insert into sections (id, course_id, instructor_id, year) values
    (34, 82, 2, 2009);
insert into sections (id, course_id, instructor_id, year) values
    (43, 32, 3, 2008);
insert into sections (id, course_id, instructor_id, year) values
    (51, 62, 4, 2008);
insert into sections (id, course_id, instructor_id, year) values
    (52, 52, 4, 2008);
insert into sections (id, course_id, instructor_id, year) values
    (53, 62, 4, 2009);
insert into sections (id, course_id, instructor_id, year) values
    (54, 52, 4, 2009);

create table enrollment (
    id          integer primary key,
    student_id  integer not null references students(id),
    section_id  integer not null references sections(id),
    grade_id    integer references grades(id)
);

insert into enrollment (id, student_id, section_id, grade_id) values
    (14, 1, 12, 8);
insert into enrollment (id, student_id, section_id, grade_id) values
    (15, 1, 13, 3);
insert into enrollment (id, student_id, section_id, grade_id) values
    (16, 1, 14, 5);
insert into enrollment (id, student_id, section_id, grade_id) values
    (17, 1, 32, 1);
insert into enrollment (id, student_id, section_id, grade_id) values
    (18, 1, 34, 2);
insert into enrollment (id, student_id, section_id, grade_id) values
    (19, 1, 53, 13);
insert into enrollment (id, student_id, section_id, grade_id) values
    (24, 3, 12, 2);
insert into enrollment (id, student_id, section_id, grade_id) values
    (25, 3, 14, 5);
insert into enrollment (id, student_id, section_id, grade_id) values
    (26, 3, 32, 1);
insert into enrollment (id, student_id, section_id, grade_id) values
    (27, 3, 34, 2);
insert into enrollment (id, student_id, section_id, grade_id) values
    (28, 3, 54, 7);
insert into enrollment (id, student_id, section_id, grade_id) values
    (34, 2, 43, 3);
insert into enrollment (id, student_id, section_id, grade_id) values
    (44, 4, 33, 4);
insert into enrollment (id, student_id, section_id, grade_id) values
    (54, 4, 53, 1);
insert into enrollment (id, student_id, section_id, grade_id) values
    (64, 6, 53, 1)
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: there is no magic or hidden optimization for `varchar` columns with length 255 (or less). The actual space usage **only** depends on the values stored in the column, not on the maximum length it can hold.

Comment: How do you know which students have not taken any classes in their major?

Comment: There's no restriction on the *major courses*. You probably need to add it to the join-condition: `inner join courses c on c.id=s.id AND s.major_id  = c.department_id`

Answer (score 0):

I tried your sample, but can't manage to have the same result as you.

I tried this :

```
select st.name, sum(value*units)/sum(units) as GPA 
from sections s
inner join enrollment e on e.section_id = s.id
inner join students st on st.id = e.student_id
inner join courses c on c.id=s.id
inner join grades g on g.value =c.units
group by st.name
```

Where I filter on the students and enrollment tables which means if the student has no courses he wont be in the results

Is it right for you ?

Comment: no , the table should  show all the students and there gpas from there respected majors. so we donnt count the grades outside of there majors. so for examnple amy , only took 1 class ( topology which is part of her major) and got a  B+.. so her gpa is 4(units)*3.3/4 = 3.3

Comment: @henryzo: If you want to show students if they didn't take any major course, yet, you must switch to outer joins.